# Get width of linear/relative layout?

Tags: android

Is it possible to get the width of a linear/relative layout, if the layout_width is set to fill_parent in the layout xml? For example, I have the following layout xml. Is it possible to find the width of the cameraSourceScreen? Thanks in advance :)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/CameraSourcesScreen"
>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/button_bar"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:background="@drawable/topbar"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center">

<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal" android:paddingLeft="20dp">

        <common.view.ToggleButton android:id="@+id/Near_Toggle"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:text="@string/NEAR_STR"
          android:textSize="18px" android:width="130dp"/>

  <common.view.ToggleButton android:id="@+id/Far_Toggle"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:text="@string/FAR_STR"
            android:textSize="18px" android:width="130dp"/>

</LinearLayout> </LinearLayout> </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an android:id to your `RelativeLayout`, then call `findViewById` as you do for the rest of the widgets and then use the getWidth method. Though... it seems that your `RelativeLayout` is filling all the screen, so why don't you just try to know the screen dimensions?

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
display.getWidth();
```

Comment: Whoa, didn't know I could do that...Thanks :)

Comment: it would not be filling the screen on android ICS+ because there is a graphic button bar on the bottom.